# How do I group a 2 dimensional list of objects in python 3.10?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I have a list of gifs. Each "gif" is a list of frame objects setup like this.

`gifs = [ [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], ...]`

I need to order them is to a list of lists where each sub-list contains the nth corresponding frame. i.e.

`orderedGifs = [ [1, 1, 1, ...], [2, 2, 2, ...], [3, 3, 3, ...], ...]`

How might I go about achieving this?

Comment: Try: `list(zip(*gifs))`

Comment: consider using numpy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @enke indicates in the comments, using `list(zip(*gifs))` gets you the transposition - but it will be a list of tuples.

If you need the groups to be lists, this works:

```
orderedGifs = list(map(list, zip(*gifs)))
```

It works because:

- `*gifs` unpacks the original `gifs` and passed all its contents to `zip()` (spreading)
- `zip()` pairs up elements in tuples from each iterable it's passed, in your case the 1st element of each list, then the 2nd, etc.
- `map(list, xs)` takes each element from `xs` and applies `list()` to it, returning an iterable of the results

So wrapping the whole thing in `list()` takes the tuples converted to lists and puts them in a list, as required.